# Why is this closeModal in React not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I have a component which render a modal component.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            fieldId: "",
            rating: -1,
            description: "",
            showModal: false //This is what checks if the modal should or shouldnt be rendered
        };
        console.log(props) //week number, beginning with 0
        this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
        this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
    }

showModal() {
    console.log("showmodal state before any click")
    console.log(this.state.showModal) //false


    this.setState({
        showModal: true
    }, () => {
        console.log("clicked show modal")
        console.log(this.state.showModal) //true
    });



}

closeModal() {
    this.setState({
        showModal: false
    }, () => {
        console.log("clicked closeModal")
        console.log(this.state.showModal) //true <------ !WHY IS THIS TRUE??
    });
}


    render() {
        var weekId = this.props.weekId;

        //current week, round up
        //lived weeks, round down
        //total weeks, round up
        if (weekId < this.props.weeksToRegisterDate) {
            return <div id={weekId} className="cube-lived"></div>
        } else if (weekId == this.props.currentWeek) {
            return <div id={weekId} title={weekId} className="cube green" onClick={this.showModal}>
                <CalendarFieldModal show={this.state.showModal} close={this.closeModal} />
            </div>
        } else {
            return <div id={weekId} title={weekId} className="cube white" onClick={this.showModal}>
                <CalendarFieldModal show={this.state.showModal} close={this.closeModal} />
            </div>


        }


    }
}
```

Basically if I click the cube it will render a modal Component, which looks like this.

```
    import React from 'react'
import './CalendarFieldModal.css'
class CalendarFieldModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        };

    }


    render() {


        if (!this.props.show) {
            return null;
        }
        // return <div className="cube-to-spawn"></div>
        return <div id="open-modal" class="modal-window">
        <div>
          <a href="#" title="Close" class="modal-close" onClick={this.props.close}>Close</a> //this triggers the function and should close the modal
          <h1>Voilà!</h1>
          <div>A CSS-only modal based on the :target pseudo-class. Hope you find it helpful.</div>
          <div><small>Check out</small></div>
          </div>
      </div>



    }
}

export default CalendarFieldModal;
```

Now in the late component I have a close button, which If i click, i can see the closeModal() function triggering and logging the console.log , so I suppose that the state is changing to. But still it doesnt close the modal. So i dont understand the issue

**EDIT:** This is how it looks  https://codesandbox.io/embed/quirky-ardinghelli-8fgtx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark you must open the preview in a new windows, or else the modal wont load

Comment: Can you post an example online, from the code I cannot see what could be wrong...

Comment: @EugenSunic https://codesandbox.io/embed/quirky-ardinghelli-8fgtx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark you must open the preview in a new windows, or else the modal wont load (the modal css is messy but its a test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor it a bit:

```
    if (weekId < this.props.weeksToRegisterDate) {
        return <div id={weekId} className="cube-lived"></div>
    } else {
        const currentStyle = (weekId == this.props.currentWeek) ? "green" : "white";
        return <div id={weekId} title={weekId} 
          className=`cube ${currentStyle}` 
          {...(!this.state.showModal && { onClick: this.showModal })}
        >
          <CalendarFieldModal show={this.state.showModal} close={this.closeModal} />
        </div>
    }
```

## Explanation

Outer `<div/>` was not `this.state.showModal` changes aware - no props change, not rerendered - no matter inner object's props changed and should be rerendered.

Comment: it actually seems to work this way, altho im having some css issues since white cubes are displayed as black (not displayed), i will try to fix it now

Comment: I think that ```const currentStyle``` is never read that way, according to visualstudiocode, thats why it doesnt render the style. ```'currentStyle' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)```

Comment: @xadm, why do you think that react cares only about the outer div? If a component state is changed, it will be re-rendered unless ```shouldComponentUpdate``` returns ```false```. So I am not sure this is the reason for this issue.

Comment: changed it like ```const currentStyle = (weekId == this.props.currentWeek) ? "green" : "white";
            var style = "cube "+ currentStyle;
            return <div id={weekId} title={weekId} className={style} ....``` so it would work

Comment: @AntoanElenkov it's rerendered but it's dropped on `reconciliation` process

Comment: @mouchin777 shame you TS ;) `const currentStyle = "cube " + (weekId == this.props.currentWeek) ? "green" : "white"; return <div id={weekId} title={weekId} className={currentStyle}`

Comment: @xadm, I don't understand why. The render function will return new different subtree which does not have the modal in it. The reconciliation process will see that the old and the new subtrees are different, so the UI should be updated. Where am I wrong?

Comment: it's part of optimalization, not the whole trees compared ... reconsilation stops on first node not differs on props assuming all deepper children should be the same - just an algorithm

Comment: notice that reconciliation works on DOM nodes (virtual, real), not components then div is a level it can be stopped

Comment: @xadm, I can't find any documentation telling that if two parent nodes in a subtree are same, child nodes are not checked for changes. And this sounds illogical to me, because you should always take care to propagate state changes in every subsequent node in order to be sure that if at lowest level there is any change, the whole tree should be repainted. I will be very thankful if you provide me with some sort of sources with such information.

Comment: forced, deeply detailed comparitions are costly ... why the component state is only shallowly compared? ... search for "uder the hood", "react internals" "diffing/reconcilation explained" etc.

Comment: @xadm, I found very detailed article about it - https://indepth.dev/inside-fiber-in-depth-overview-of-the-new-reconciliation-algorithm-in-react/ where clearly is written - **"Only once all branches starting with child nodes are completed does it complete the work for the parent node and backtracks"**. There is also animation showing the way one node is marked as completely reconciled - https://vimeo.com/302222454

Comment: I really don't care if it is in reconcilation (or diffing) process - it just work this way behind the scene - not the right place for this discussion, EOT for me.